# puppetserver gem install does not respect http proxy

Tags: puppet

I am currently migrating to Puppet 4.x. I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 with Puppet 4.2.3 and Puppetserver 2.1.2. I must add some additional gems to the server and to some agents. Both commands hang indefinitely.

```
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver gem install -V --no-rdoc --no-ri -p http://myproxy.com:8080 rest-client
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem install -V --no-rdoc --no-ri -p http://myproxy.com:8080 rest-client
```

I get the same behavior when I omit the proxy settings.

When I run the `gem install`command on the same machine from the installed Ruby 1.9.3 environment. Everything works perfectly, so the proxy is working fine:

```
gem install -V --no-rdoc --no-ri rest-client -p http://myproxy.com:8080
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Found
GET http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rest-client-1.8.0.gemspec.rz
302 Found
GET http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/rest-client-1.8.0.gemspec.rz
200 OK
...
```

Has anybody an idea how to solve the problem. It becomes a hard blocker for my right now.

Comment: Have you tried watching the `gem` process with `strace` to see where it gets stuck and what it's trying to do?

Comment: Have a look to my answer posted subsequently. Have you got an idea of how to solve the problem without that hacking workaround?

Comment: o_O Does your machine suffer from a lack of entropy? You could try installing `havaged` or a similar tool.

Comment: Your solution sounds much better... I will give it a try.

Comment: `havaged`works pretty good and can be managed via Puppet... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue... `jstack` gave me the following trace:

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fce4400a000 nid=0x2f89 runnable [0x00007fce4d709000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$URLSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(SeedGenerator.java:551)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(SeedGenerator.java:139)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:197)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:214)
    - locked <0x00000000c34ba1e8> (a sun.security.provider.SecureRandom)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:466)
    - locked <0x00000000c34ba190> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
    at org.jruby.ext.securerandom.SecureRandomLibrary.nextBytes(SecureRandomLibrary.java:49)
    at org.jruby.ext.securerandom.SecureRandomLibrary.nextBytes(SecureRandomLibrary.java:42)
    at org.jruby.ext.securerandom.SecureRandomLibrary.random_bytes(SecureRandomLibrary.java:21)
    at org.jruby.ext.securerandom.SecureRandomLibrary$INVOKER$s$random_bytes.call(SecureRandomLibrary$INVOKER$s$random_bytes.gen)
```

The problem can be fixed by adding `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` to `/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/gem`.

**Update**

A much better solution is to install another tool like `havaged` that remedies low-entropy conditions. A Puppet module can be found here: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/stm/haveged